# How to filter crossfilter dimension of array

Tags: crossfilter

How to filter crossfilter dimension of array

I have created following dimension

```
    var typeSeriesDimension = data.dimension(function(d)

      { 

    return [d.user_code, d.count];

 });
```

If I apply filter as typeSeriesDimension.filter([5,10]).top(1)

I should get an object having user_code=5 and count=10 but crossfilter consider [5,10] as a range and returns different object.

Comment: You could try  typeSeriesDimension.filterExact([5,10]). Dimensions of arrays can be a little strange though, so beware.

Comment: Thank you @Ethan !
filterExact([5,10]) worked.